# How to load ktx file with cubemap in three.js?

Tags: three.js, pvrtc

I maked `ktx` file with `cubemap`. and it encode to `pvrtc`. then load to this file in `three.js`. and I could see this console warning.

```
number of faces expected1, but found 6
```

I can't see the material that this file is applied to.

I'm using `three.js` version `0.107.0`

How can I use this `ktx` file?

Comment: This error means that three.js does not support cubemaps in its KTX loader — you may need to file a feature request on its GitHub repository.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Oh.. Okay I see.. Is there a possibility that the version of three.js could have been solved as it went up?

Comment: You can see the latest code here: [KTXLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/loaders/KTXLoader.js) ... it doesn't look like it, no.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thank you answer to me.. humm Then, Should I upload this problem to Three.js github Issue?

Comment: I think so, yes. Especially if you can share an example of a KTX file that you want to load.